# Trouble having an element fixed in HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I have been trying to make a segmented circle using HTML/CSS, but two pieces of the circle (left and bottom) don't stay in a fixed place when the resolution of the screen is decreased or increase, but the other parts do. This is the code I've right now:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@100&display=swap');


html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #457CB0;
}


.circle {
    background: #457CB0;
    border: 50px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .6);
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0.475em 0.475em 0.6em 0.6em rgba(15, 28, 63, 0.125);
    height: 27em;
    width: 27em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
}


.cirlce2 {
    border: 20px dashed rgba(255, 255, 255, .6);
    border-radius: 70%;
    height: 25em;
    width: 25em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
}

.myCircle2 {
    border: 20px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    border-radius: 70%;
    height: 7.2em;
    width: 7.2em;
    background-color: #457CB0;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
}

.textCircle {
    color: #ffffff;
    position: absolute;
    width: 155px;
    height: 250px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
}

.myCircle3 {
    border-bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    height: 320px;
    width: 320px;
    border-radius: 250px 250px 250px 250px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
    border-bottom: 0;
    border: 100px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}

.div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 60.25%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    height: 152px;
    width: 320px;
    border-radius: 0 0 150px 150px;
    background-color: #457CB0;
}

.myCircle4 {
    border: 7px solid #457CB0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 21em;
    width: 21em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 1;
}

.bottom-right-quarter-circle {
    height: 145px;
    width: 155px;
    top: 51.9%;
    left: 50.3%;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 0 0 250px 0;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
}

.bottom-left {
    height: 145px;
    width: 155px;
    top: 51.9%;
    left: 37.5%;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 250px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Circle</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="CircleType-master/dist/circletype.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="circle.css">
</head>

<body class="bg">

    <div class="circle"></div>

    <div class="cirlce2"></div>
    <div class="myCircle"></div>
    <div class="myCircle2"></div>
    <div class="myCircle3"></div>
    <div class="myCircle4"></div>

<div class="div"></div>

    <div class="bottom-right-quarter-circle"></div>
    <div class="bottom-left"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is the code for the left & bottom specifically:

```
<div class="bottom-left"></div>
<div class="div"></div>
```

```
.bottom-left {
    height: 145px;
    width: 155px;
    top: 51.9%;
    left: 37.5%;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 250px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
}
.div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 60.25%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    height: 152px;
    width: 320px;
    border-radius: 0 0 150px 150px;
    background-color: #457CB0;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use units in `%` or `vh`, `vw`? Why duplicating `meta name="viewport"`?

Comment: Hi, I've used the % units, but they don't seem to work for those two objects.

Comment: try putting .bottom-left and .div in a flex box and for flex box do space-even

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't seem to work again!

Answer (score 0):

you should put the divs inside each others so they can be related to each others

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Circle</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="CircleType-master/dist/circletype.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="bg">
    <style>
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@100&display=swap');
        html,
        body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background-color: #457CB0;
        }
        
        .circle {
            background: #457CB0;
            border: 50px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .6);
            border-radius: 50%;
            box-shadow: 0.475em 0.475em 0.6em 0.6em rgba(15, 28, 63, 0.125);
            height: 27em;
            width: 27em;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            margin: auto;
        }
        
        .cirlce2 {
            border: 20px dashed rgba(255, 255, 255, .6);
            border-radius: 70%;
            height: 25em;
            width: 25em;
            top: 0rem;
            left: -0.15rem;
            position: absolute;
            margin: -2rem 0rem 0rem -2rem;
        }
        
        .myCircle3 {
            border-bottom: 0;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            height: 320px;
            width: 320px;
            border-radius: 250px 250px 250px 250px;
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
            border-bottom: 0;
            border: 100px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
        }
        
        .div {
            position: absolute;
            top: 10.33rem;
            left: 10.33rem;
            border-radius: 100%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            height: 152px;
            width: 152px;
            background-color: #457CB0;
        }
        
        .myCircle4 {
            border: 7px solid #457CB0;
            border-radius: 50%;
            height: 21em;
            width: 21em;
            top: -.1rem;
            left: -0.1rem;
            position: absolute;
            margin: auto;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        
        .bottom-right-quarter-circle {
            height: 20px;
            width: 325px;
            left: -6.25rem;
            top: 40%;
            position: absolute;
            background-color: #457CB0;
            z-index: 50;
        }
        
        .bottom-left {
            height: 140px;
            width: 20px;
            bottom: -6.7rem;
            left: 3.3rem;
            position: absolute;
            margin: auto;
            display: block;
            border-radius: 250px;
            background-color: #457CB0;
        }
    </style>

    <div class="circle">
        <div class="cirlce2"></div>
        <div class="myCircle3">
            <div class="bottom-right-quarter-circle"></div>
            <div class="bottom-left"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="div"></div>
        <div class="myCircle4"></div>
    </div>





</body>

</html>
```